# Showing or hiding a column in PostgreSQL in the same query

Tags: postgresql

How can I show or hide a column, in the same query, based on a boolean value? The app I'm using allows for JavaScript to be put in between double curly brackets, and the boolean will come from that.

I'm imagining a solution like this:

```
SELECT
  accounts.email,
  IF( {{my JavaScript will return a boolean here}} )
    accounts.zip
WHERE accounts.email = 'none@none.com';
```

And if the boolean value were true, the result would be:

```
+---------------+-------+
|     email     |  zip  |
+---------------+-------+
| none@none.com | 20500 |
+---------------+-------+
```

And if the boolean value were false, the result would be:

```
+---------------+
|     email     |
+---------------+
| none@none.com |
+---------------+
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: What is the source of the boolean value?  You can't really do this without dynamic SQL.

Comment: The app I'm using allows for JavaScript to be put in between double curly brackets, and the boolean will come from that.

Comment: Maybe add your JavaScript code if possible.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: what is the query produced in you example, what does the boolean look like in the query that's sent to postgresql, are there spaces inserted or the value?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically change which columns to select in SQL itself; you have to do it at the application level. So, if you need to follow the pattern you have in your existing code, you have to assign the columns in JavaScript rather than in SQL:

```
var query = 
`SELECT
  accounts.email
  { booleanResult ? ', accounts.zip' : '' }
FROM myTable
WHERE accounts.email = 'none@none.com'`
```

That way when your boolean is true, your query is `SELECT accounts.email, accounts.zip FROM ...`. When it is false, your query is `SELECT accounts.email FROM ...`.